# How to access class variables from within blade template

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

My controller index file looks like this:

```
class KJVController extends Controller
{

    public $book = "Genesis";
    public $chapter = 1;    
    public function index() {
        $results = KJV::where('book', '=', $this->book)->where('chapter', '=', $this->chapter)->get();
        return view("bible", compact('results'));
    }

}
```

And in my blade template I want to be able to show the variables above (`$book`,`$chapter`).

I tried:

`{{ KJVController::book }}`
`{{ KJVController->book }}`

I can't seem to access it.  How can I display this information in my blade template?

Comment: @Andrew.. How wrong you are....

Comment: @Andrew no, my instinct is to do that but its the laravel way.  I learned that the hard way.

Comment: Indeed, I removed the comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass these variables to the view first:

```
return view("bible", ['results' => $results, 'book' => $this->book, 'chapter' => $this->chapter]);
```

In the `bible` view:

```
{{ $book }}
```

Or you can just do this:

```
{{ app('App\Controllers\KJVController')->book }}
```

Comment: So are you saying it's just not possible? (Also hello @Alexey  again!)

Comment: @Chud37 I've updated the answer with an example of using IoC container. It's possible, it's just nobody does that.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin yes.  But I passed it through as you suggested, I just figured that the controller was available in the view but I guess not.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing wrong with your controller query. You just aren't returning the variable. You're trying to return the controller and as you're running `->get()`, it returns an array. Therefore, you need to do this within the blade:

```
@foreach ($results as $book)
    {{$book->book}}{{$book->chapter}}
@endforeach
```

[Blade documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade)

Comment: I think OP wants to display `public` variables and not the collection data.